# Rebuilding a URL without a query string parameter

Tags: java, jsp, url, url-parameters

Let's say I have a page which lists things and has various filters for that list in a sidebar.  As an example, consider [this page on ebuyer.com](http://www.ebuyer.com/store/Home-&-Leisure/cat/Batteries/subcat/AAA-Batteries/Duracell?price=0%20TO%205&q=batteries), which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of filter on ebuyer.com]

Those filters on the left are controlled by query string parameters, and the link to remove one of those filters contains the URL of the current page but without that one query string parameter in it.

Is there a way in JSP of easily constructing that "remove" link?  I.e., is there a quick way to reproduce the current URL, but with a single query string parameter removed, or do I have to manually rebuild the URL by reading the query string parameters, adding them to the base URL, and skipping the one that I want to leave out?

My current plan is to make something like the following method available as a custom EL function:

```
    public String removeQueryStringParameter(
            HttpServletRequest request, 
            String paramName, 
            String paramValue) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(request.getRequestURI());

        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> param : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
            String key = param.getKey();
            String encodedKey = URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8");

            for (String value : param.getValue()) {
                if (key.equals(paramName) && value.equals(paramValue)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (first) {
                    url.append('?');
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    url.append('&');
                }
                url.append(encodedKey);
                url.append('=');
                url.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
            }

        }
        return url.toString();
    }
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

The better way is to use [`UrlEncodedQueryString`](https://java.net/projects/urlencodedquerystring/pages/Home).

> `UrlEncodedQueryString` can be used to set, append or remove parameters
>   from a query string:
>
> ```
>  URI uri = new URI("/forum/article.jsp?id=2&para=4");
>  UrlEncodedQueryString queryString = UrlEncodedQueryString.parse(uri);
>  queryString.set("id", 3);
>  queryString.remove("para");
>  System.out.println(queryString);
> ```

Comment: Nice, thanks.  I'd still have to expose a custom EL function to use it in JSPs, though.

Comment: Incidentally, there isn't a built-in method to remove a param with a given value.  For example, consider `?cat=1&cat=2&cat=3` - if I wanted to remove just "cat=1", I'd have to use `getValues("cat")` to get at the underlying `List<String>` and manually remove the target value from that list.  The docs do not _guarantee_ that the list returned by `getValues` is the underlying list (as opposed to a clone of it).  Although the source code shows it is, the devs are free to change that in a future version because it's undocumented.